# How to store data in Progressive Web Applications in .Net core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web, progressive

I want to store offline data in Progressive Web Applications in .Net core 2.1 in user mobile or i-pad. Once user will come, online, it will automatically send the data to the server .Please let me know any reference.

Answer (score 1):

.Net Core does not run in the browser (although Blazor is promising that). So you will have to write Web APIs using ASP.NET Core and then you will need to have SPA (Single Page Application) written in Angular or similar JavaScript based framework. Then SPA can be made as "Progressive App" and it can run offline in the browser.
For storing data "in the browser" you have few options: LocalStorage, IndexedDb, WebSQL and etc. [Here is good performance comparison of all](https://nolanlawson.github.io/database-comparison/)